# How to open a .so file?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I downloaded an application on my android. It contains a `.so` file. I have issues opening it. I tried win rar 7 zip etc. as recomended here http://file.org/extension/so

This application is mostly composed of text files, so I wanted to get those files and print them

How can I deal with the `.so` ?

Comment: It contains object code. What do you think you mean by "opening" it, and what do you hope to do with it after it's open?

Answer (score 8):

An .so file is a binary file used as a native library on Android. Normally it's a part of an Android application. If you want to see its content, you need to open it as a binary file in a binary (hex) viewer. In any case you won't see much there, but hex code. You cannot launch it either. You need an application that loads and launches it.

Comment: Can i used it in my code if i know the native method supported by it. @beworker

Comment: @Nepster If the rights on the file or the file itself belong to you, then yes. Otherwise this will be copyright infringement.